# What prevented the Romans from naval expansion?

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-empire, ships

Now, I have a very poor understanding of history (my high school didn't even have a history class), so if I'm missing something please point it out.

The ancient Roman Empire was pretty large for its day, and conquered the entire Mediterranean Sea. Presumably ships played a role in this, either for conquest (at first) and for trade and troop movements (later).

But the Romans never really expanded further than the Mediterranean. At least, not by ship. Their land conquests look impressive, but they never really seem to have become a maritime empire. Never pushed down to sail around (or conquer) sub-Saharan Africa. Never pushed down into the Red Sea. Never reached the Americas.

I once wondered about this, and was told the reason was Roman technology wasn't up to such long journeys.

But what technologies did they lack that they would have needed? When those distances WERE first traveled, its not like they had steam engines or freezers. Or even a stronger tree or nails. Even canned food post-dated the colonization of the Americas by 200 years.

The Romans clearly had ships, and sails for their ships. They understood sailing. So what prevented them from expanding?

Comment: Re "the Romans never really expanded further than the Mediterranean. At least, not by ship". Are you aware that the Roman reached the British Isles, as well as the southern reaches of the North See from the mouth of the Rhine to the mouth of the Elbe and as far as the Jutland peninsula?

Comment: Have a look at [Roman navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_navy#Fleets_in_Western_Europe) and consider also the comment from @njuffa (i.e your question is based partly on a false premise).   Please edit your question  to make it clear exactly what it is you would like to know which is not covered by the Wikipedia link.

Comment: You may also want to consider whether the *skill* and *experience level* of Roman sailors was up to the challenges of the North Sea (which in a 19th century German sailor's rhyme is referred to as the "murderous sea"). During the Germanicus campaigns of 15 AD and 16 AD, on the return trip from the Ems to their winter quarters, the Romans were caught out by fall storms along the North Sea coast in both years (wiping out parts of the land party in a storm surge in 15 AD; scattering and sinking a large part of their fleet in 16 AD): Tacitus, *Annals*, 1, 70 and Tacitus, *Annals* 2, 23.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786).  Why doesn't [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_navy) doesn't answer the question. I suspect that research and adoption of new technologies (naval expansion requires new ships, new navigational methods, charts, etc.) are only sensible when further land expansion is blocked.  Rome invested primarily in infantry tactics.

Comment: You make several false assumptions here like the Romans never pushed down the red sea?  Read the Periplus Maris, dated to around 50ad, it details the exact routes from Rome, out the Red Sea and to India and Sri Lanka.  Chinese writers have a Roman diplomatic ship in the seas off Vietnam about 150 years later.  There were also several small roman settlements off the west coast of africa, so they did two of the things you think they didnt.

Comment: The Roman Empire had expanded as far as it was *profitable* to do.

Answer (score 4):

The Roman fleet largely relied on [galleys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_navy#Types_of_ships). The Romans had nothing like a [carvel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caravel) or [carrack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrack), let alone a [galleon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galleon).  Several reasons come together for this.

- The technology of sails and rigging was not as well developed as in the 15th century, when European exploration happened. Oars were required for maneuvering, or to travel upwind.
- Before gunpowder, warships relied on ramming and boarding, with just a few catapults or greek fire. Again that required oars for maneuvering.
- Rowing ships need large crews. Large crews need lots of food and water. That reduced the endurance of galleys, which would travel along the coasts and go to shore every night, or at least every couple of days. That means they had to be light enough for beaching.

A galley was better suited for use within the Mediterranean than outside of it. You might look at the end of the galley era, the [battle of Lepanto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Lepanto), and compare it with the [Spanish Armada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ships_of_the_Spanish_Armada) a decade later.

The Romans had some [quite large ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isis_(ship)), but those were for established cargo routes, not exploration. The comment by [njuffa](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/8149/njuffa) points out that Rome used transports, not just warships, but some of those used by Caesar to [invade Britain](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Commentaries_on_the_Gallic_War/Book_4#22) were held up by contrary winds.

Comment: When Caesar invaded Britain in 54 BC, the invasion fleet supposedly consisted of 600 to 800 vessels. It seems highly unlikely that many of them were galleys. If I recall correctly, Tacitus' account of Germanicus' Northern German campaigns mentions a large fleet, but a galley only in connection with the commander.

Comment: This is good as far as it goes, but I think there's a lot more detail needed. I find your connection between gunpowder/ramming and ship design interesting -- is there evidence to support it?  I was under the impression that pretty good sailing ships predated guns on ships by centuries.

Comment: @MarkOlson, you are right regarding the level of detail, and "pretty good" is a judgement call. But guns on ships seem to predate the carvel.

Comment: You could also add that the Romans were mostly expanding by contacting another people and then conflicting with them. They were not ready to build from nothing a naval expedition

Answer (score 0):

Logistics (cost) x Wealth of Targets (benefit). The same issues when asking "why did not Rome conquer Scotland?"

Romans went into the Red Sea, and got their asses handed to them due to logistic issues and treachery from their guides. Then they did not emphasize this less successful part of their history...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NeUCXM2WwY4

They also tried to explore the Nile, and were similarly unsuccessful (https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=romans+nile+expedition)
There is difficult marshy terrain before the source of the Nile - the question was only settled on the XIX century anyway.

In the comments, @njuffa tells us (I did not know about the fleet):
Germanicus did build a large North Sea fleet for the campaign of 16 AD against Germanic tribes. Tacitus, Annals, 2, 6 (Loeb translation): " Silius and Caecina were made responsible for the construction of a fleet. A thousand vessels were considered enough, and these were built at speed. Some were short craft with very little poop or prow, and broad-bellied, the more easily to withstand a heavy sea: others had flat bottoms, enabling them to run aground without damage; while still more were fitted with rudders at each end, so as to head either way the moment the oarsmen reversed their stroke." –

Useful against German tribes near the coast, although this description does not look like a ocean going fleet for large distances. Anyway, the deeper Roman incursions in Germany did not led to permanent conquest ([Teutoburg Forest and later campaigns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Teutoburg_Forest)...).

Thus, in the North, The Romans had short lived attempts to expansion by naval power, with mediocre long term results. Why would they invest in naval tech to go much further away in the North? If Scotland was too poor/cold/remote to sustain a Roman Army in conquest, what about Ireland, Scandinavia or Iceland?

In the south, Romans knew the Sahara: to supply an army across the Sahara would be unthinkable, and they would realize that easily.

Somebody on this site recommended this blog:
https://acoup.blog/2022/07/15/collections-logistics-how-did-they-do-it-part-i-the-problem/

A summary about ancient (or pre-railroad) logistics, explaining why ancient armies could not go everywhere, even if it looks easy when looking into a map. It is a long but rewarding reading if you are interested on these issues.  Also, from the same guy:

https://acoup.blog/2022/05/27/collections-total-generalship-commanding-pre-modern-armies-part-i-reports/

In short, they did try, in almost all directions possible. But logistics limited them.

Comment: Germanicus did build a large North Sea fleet for the campaign of 16 AD against Germanic tribes. Tacitus, *Annals*, 2, 6 (Loeb translation): " Silius and Caecina were made responsible for the construction of a fleet. A thousand vessels were considered enough, and these were built at speed. Some were short craft with very little poop or prow, and broad-bellied, the more easily to withstand a heavy sea: others had flat bottoms, enabling them to run aground without damage; while still more were fitted with rudders at each end, so as to head either way the moment the oarsmen reversed their stroke."

Comment: @njuffa thanks, I incorporated your comment to make it permanent, if you do not mind.